# C# How to re-run code in form load

Tags: c#, string, validation, inputbox, form-load

for my program i'm writing i want to ask for a name and if the input has a number or other unwanted input to loop back and do it again.

This is my current code

```
private void gameForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string value = "Type here";
    if (globalVariables.InputBox("Name", "Please enter name", ref value) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        name = value;
        if (name.All(char.IsLetter))
        {
            lblName.Text = value;
        }
        else
        {
        }
    } 
}
```

How can i re-run this code if invalid input is present?

Comment: Use a `do-while` loop.

Comment: *Form_Load* is not a good place to implement that logic. Use a loop in another form/code,  and create this form if the input satisfies your criteria.

Comment: Write another method called EnterName().  Move your code into that method.  Call it from your Load event handler.  Call it from where ever else you need it.  Easy peasy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use a `while` loop

```
while(true)
{
   if (globalVariables.InputBox("Name", "Please enter name", ref value) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        name = value;
        if (name.All(char.IsLetter))
        {
            lblName.Text = value;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvoted and I don't see a reason for downvote as well but I think a `do-while` loop would be better here.

Comment: i didn't do it and i actually changed it to this as it works better @Rahul

Comment: @Ranga6669, Comment was not for you; rather in general. Moreover, I knew very well that you didn't down voted cause down voting requires 250 reputation which you don't have.

Comment: @Rahul troll algud. How would this be done to use numbers instead of a string?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new method  public void NameCheck()"Then put the code you want to run in there"

Then in you're page load you put NameCheck(); to call the method.

So if the name contains numbers you call the NameCheck(); again in the else.

```
    public void NameCheck()
    {
        string value = "Type here";
        if (globalVariables.InputBox("Name", "Please enter name", ref value) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            name = value;
            if (name.All(char.IsLetter))
            {
                lblName.Text = value;
            }
            else
            {
                NameCheck();
            }
        }
    }


    private void gameForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NameCheck();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    private void gameForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        reAsk:
        string value = "Type here";
        if (globalVariables.InputBox("Name", "Please enter name", ref value) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            name = value;
            if (name.All(char.IsLetter))
            {
                lblName.Text = value;
            }
            else
            {                      
                goto reAsk;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This seems like it'll be the easiest way to do it but when i add ":reAsk" it gives me a red line and wont work is this a variable i dont have or something ?? @Khan